# Are all metric tensors of 3 dimensional surfaces 2x2?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I was doing some work with the volume surface area ratio when I worked it out, I had assumed the metric tensor to be 3x3. I looked for some examples of surfaces test on trecs.se but I saw that all of the first fundemental forms of the surfaces in the surface index were 2x2. Am I dealing with a small minority where this is true or is there some way to introduce a third parameter keeping the surface the same?

Comment: The type of a tensor in a vector space (in your case, the tangent planes to the surface) depends on its number of arguments, not on the dimension of the domain space. In other words, the fact that your surface is embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ is irrelevant. The special thing here is that the first fundamental form is the *restriction* of the scalar product, with is a tensor on the full space $\Bbb R^3$. Now, if $W \subseteq V$ and you have a tensor on $V$, in general there are several ways to extend it to a tensor on $V$.

Comment: @Ivo Terek then are there multiple unique parameterizations of one surface that have the same resulting metric tensor or does the metric tensor "encode" information about the surface through 1 parameterization?

Comment: Different parametrizations do not give different metric tensors. A tensor is something *intrinsic*, it does not depend on the chosen parametrization. The first fundamental form is the restriction of the ambient scalar product to the tangent planes to the surface, period. No bases were used. A parametrization for the surface will give a coordinate basis, and this basis will give you metric components $g_{ij}$. A different parametrization will give you a different coordinate basis, and hence different metric components $\widetilde{g}_{ij}$. These are related by the usual transformation law.